# vimscript closing character skipping

Tags: vim

I have been working on developing a vim plugin for a little while, but have been stuck on a roadblock for a few weeks. My is written in vimscript, and it is a simple auto-pairing program for the `()`, `{}`, `[]`, `""`, `''` pairs. I have been trying to get it to skip over over the right of the closing characters ( `)`, `}`, `]` ) when it already exits. My focus right now is getting it to work just for the `)`, `]`, `}` characters.

My issue is that I having trouble getting the function to execute when the closing character input is entered.

Here's what I have tried so far:
First Attempt:

```
inoremap ( ()
inoremap (h ()<LEFT>
inoremap (l ();<RETURN>
inoremap (" ("")<LEFT><LEFT>
inoremap (' ('')<LEFT><LEFT>
inoremap (; ();<DOWN>
inoremap ) call CloseChar()

inoremap [ []
inoremap [h []<LEFT>
inoremap ] call CloseChar()

inoremap { {}
inoremap {h {}<LEFT>
inoremap {<RETURN> {<RETURN><TAB><RETURN><BACKSPACE>}<UP><TAB>
inoremap } call CloseChar()

inoremap " ""
inoremap "h ""<LEFT>
inoremap "l "";<RETURN>

inoremap ' ''
inoremap 'h ''<LEFT>
inoremap 'l '';<RETURN>

function CloseChar()
    if matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') ==  '}'
        return <RIGHT>
    elseif matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') == ')'
        return <RIGHT>
    elseif matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') == ']'
            return <RIGHT>
    elseif matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') == '"'
            return <RIGHT>
    elseif matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') == '''
            return <RIGHT>
    endif
endfunction
```

Second Attempt:

```
inoremap ( ()
inoremap (h ()<LEFT>
inoremap (l ();<RETURN>
inoremap (" ("")<LEFT><LEFT>
inoremap (' ('')<LEFT><LEFT>
inoremap (; ();<DOWN>
inoremap ) :call CloseChar()

inoremap [ []
inoremap [h []<LEFT>
inoremap ] :call CloseChar()

inoremap { {}
inoremap {h {}<LEFT>
inoremap {<RETURN> {<RETURN><TAB><RETURN><BACKSPACE>}<UP><TAB>
inoremap } :call CloseChar()

inoremap " ""
inoremap "h ""<LEFT>
inoremap "l "";<RETURN>

inoremap ' ''
inoremap 'h ''<LEFT>
inoremap 'l '';<RETURN>

function CloseChar()
    if matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') ==  '}'
        return <RIGHT>
    elseif matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') == ')'
        return <RIGHT>
    elseif matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') == ']'
            return <RIGHT>
    elseif matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') == '"'
            return <RIGHT>
    elseif matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') == '''
            return <RIGHT>
    endif
endfunction
```

Third Attempt:

```
inoremap ( ()
inoremap (h ()<LEFT>
inoremap (l ();<RETURN>
inoremap (" ("")<LEFT><LEFT>
inoremap (' ('')<LEFT><LEFT>
inoremap (; ();<DOWN>
inoremap <silent>) :call CloseChar()

inoremap [ []
inoremap [h []<LEFT>
inoremap <silent>] :call CloseChar()

inoremap { {}
inoremap {h {}<LEFT>
inoremap {<RETURN> {<RETURN><TAB><RETURN><BACKSPACE>}<UP><TAB>
inoremap <silent>} :call CloseChar()

inoremap " ""
inoremap "h ""<LEFT>
inoremap "l "";<RETURN>

inoremap ' ''
inoremap 'h ''<LEFT>
inoremap 'l '';<RETURN>

function CloseChar()
    if matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') ==  '}'
        return <RIGHT>
    elseif matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') == ')'
        return <RIGHT>
    elseif matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') == ']'
            return <RIGHT>
    elseif matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') == '"'
            return <RIGHT>
    elseif matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') == '''
            return <RIGHT>
    endif
endfunction
```

Last Attempt:

```
inoremap ( ()
inoremap (h ()<LEFT>
inoremap (l ();<RETURN>
inoremap (" ("")<LEFT><LEFT>
inoremap (' ('')<LEFT><LEFT>
inoremap (; ();<DOWN>

inoremap [ []
inoremap [h []<LEFT>

inoremap { {}
inoremap {h {}<LEFT>
inoremap {<RETURN> {<RETURN><TAB><RETURN><BACKSPACE>}<UP><TAB>

inoremap " ""
inoremap "h ""<LEFT>
inoremap "l "";<RETURN>

inoremap ' ''
inoremap 'h ''<LEFT>
inoremap 'l '';<RETURN>

function CloseChar()
    if matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') ==  '}'
        return <RIGHT>
    elseif matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') == ')'
        return <RIGHT>
    elseif matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') == ']'
            return <RIGHT>
    elseif matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') == '"'
            return <RIGHT>
    elseif matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') == '''
            return <RIGHT>
    endif
endfunction

call CloseChar()
```

Instead of `CloseChar()` being executed, a new `)`, `]`, `}` is inserted. The sources for solutions I have referenced [learnvimscriptthehardway](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com) and [Five Minute Vimscript](http://andrewscala.com/vimscript/); as well as a few stackoverflow posts (I do not have a high enough reputation to link all the relevant forums and articles I have found, sorry).

So, essentially, I am stuck and am inquiring help to fix my plugin so that it works.

Note:
Don't know if it makes a big difference or not, but I am using vim via Windows Subsystem for Linux (wsl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am considering the ***first attempt*** in this working little improvement:

```
inoremap ( ()
inoremap (h ()<LEFT>
inoremap (l ();<RETURN>
inoremap (" ("")<LEFT><LEFT>
inoremap (' ('')<LEFT><LEFT>
inoremap (; ();<DOWN>
inoremap ) <Esc><RIGHT>:call CloseChar()<cr>i

inoremap [ []
inoremap [h []<LEFT>
inoremap ] <Esc><RIGHT>:call CloseChar()<cr>i


inoremap { {}
inoremap {h {}<LEFT>
inoremap {<RETURN> {<RETURN><TAB><RETURN><BACKSPACE>}<UP><TAB>
inoremap } <Esc><RIGHT>:call CloseChar()<cr>i

inoremap " ""
inoremap "h ""<LEFT>
inoremap "l "";<RETURN>

inoremap ' ''
inoremap 'h ''<LEFT>
inoremap 'l '';<RETURN>

function! CloseChar()
    if matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.') =~#  '\v\)|]|"|''|}'
        normal! l
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help. This works perfectly for me.

Comment: Happy to help !

Answer (score 0):

Your initial problem is that you're trying to call a function from an insert-mode mapping without going into a mode that permits calling that function. It cannot work.

The best approach would be to have an `inoremap-<expr>` that returns either what you've typed or `<right>` (actually, you want to return `<c-g>U<right>` in order to support redo) if the character under the cursor is the same as the key you've just typed.

Note that playing with `<esc>` + `i` has too many side effects. Prefer `<c-o>`, or even better here an `inoremap-<expr>` as I've said.

Also, if you map `(` and `(;` (IOW, just a key, AND this same key followed by anything else), you'll observe mappings that are not triggered right away, but after a timeout. After many experiments on brackets subject (I've been maintaining [mappings](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/) that have evolved over almost 20 years), my conclusion is: Have only one mapping that starts with the bracket opening character, and as many contextualized mappings as needed to insert a newline in between the brackets, or close all opened brackets, or close all opened brackets and append a semi-colon, and so on.